# How to do pagination based on a calculated column

Tags: sql-server, pagination, calculated-columns

I have a problem ascribable to this simplified version:
I have a table in Sql Server 2008 like this (it's a denormalized table specific for my search):

```
ItemId | CategoryId | Descr       | ExtendedDescription
0001   |          1 | Mouse X     | Blue mouse
0002   |          1 | Blue Pen    | Beautiful ....
0003   |          2 | Blue Pencil | Pencil with ...
0004   |          2 | Eraser      | Eraser with ....
```

I need to search a word (like "Blue") in this table, assign a rank to the result based on where the word appears and group the result by CategoryId summing the rank.
I am able to do that; the problem arises when I try to paginating the result.
This is the stored procedure that I tried (now the word to search is fixed, but I know how to make it a parameter; I know also how to filter ID to have pagination):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSearch]

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT 
      [CategoryId],
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN (PATINDEX('%Blue%', Descr) > 0) THEN 100 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN (PATINDEX('%Blue%', ExtendedDescription) > 0) THEN 10 ELSE 0 END
        ) AS Ranking, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CategoryId DESC) ID
  FROM [dbo].[Data]
  where (Descr like '%Blue%' or
    ExtendedDescription like '%Blue%') 
GROUP BY CategoryId
ORDER BY Ranking DESC
END
```

With this sp I get the following result:

```
CategoryId | Ranking | ID
0001       |   110   | 2
0002       |   100   | 1
```

The problem is: to paginating the result, I need that ID (ROW_NUMBER) is generated ordering descending the Ranking, while in this way it's generated in the order of CategoryId.
If I try to change the sp in this way:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Ranking DESC) ID
```

I can't save the sp because Ranking is not a column.
Do you have some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by using `Common Table expression` ([CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) we can solve this

Try this

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT 

      [CategoryId],
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN (PATINDEX('%Blue%', Descr) > 0) THEN 100 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN (PATINDEX('%Blue%', ExtendedDescription) > 0) THEN 10 ELSE 0 END
        ) AS Ranking, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CategoryId DESC) ID
  FROM [dbo].[Data]
  where (Descr like '%Blue%' or
    ExtendedDescription like '%Blue%') 
GROUP BY CategoryId
)

SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER(ORDER BY Ranking DESC) AS r_no,
       Ranking,
       ID
FROM cte
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed! My next manual will be about Sql Server because I was unaware about CTE.